# Is it possible to add custom properties to c# enum object?

Tags: c#, enums, system.componentmodel

Using c# Is it possible using to associate properties for each enum items?

I have used the [Description Attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) to add English description to an `enum` item.

To add English description to each item I have done the following

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    [Description("My First Item")]
    First,

    [Description("My Second Item")]
    Second,

    [Description("My Third Item")]
    Third
}
```

Then I added an extension method to my `enum` called `GetDescription()` which allows me to get the description like so

```
public static string GetDescription(this Enum value)
{
    Type type = value.GetType();

    string name = Enum.GetName(type, value);

    if (name != null)
    {
        FieldInfo field = type.GetField(name);
        if (field != null)
        {
            DescriptionAttribute attr = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(field, typeof(DescriptionAttribute)) as DescriptionAttribute;
            if (attr != null)
            {
                return attr.Description;
            }
        }
    }

    return name;
}
```

However, it will help me a lot if I am able to assign a class or construct a new object.

Is it possible/How can I do something like the follow?

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    [Description("My First Item"), new { IsFirst = true, UnitType = 1}]
    First
}
```

or using a class

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    [Description("My First Item"), new MyCustomClass(true, 1)]
    First
}
```

Comment: You can [create your own custom attribute class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/attributes/writing-custom-attributes).

Comment: At this point, shouldn't you just use polymorphism instead of using enums?

Comment: Enum's are essentially integers and you want to store an int, string and class, use a `Tuple<int, string, object> tuple = new Tuple<int, string, object>(1, "First Item",  new MyCustomClass(true, 1));`

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault can you please show an example of how to do that?

Comment: @MikeA if one of the answers solved your problem, please mark it as resolved. If not please clarify what still is missing in the existing answers.

Answer (score 8):

You can decorate elements with custom Attributes. Those can contain nearly anything you want.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class DescriptorAttribute : Attribute
{
    public bool IsFirst { get; }
    public int UnitType { get; }

    public DescriptorAttribute(bool isFirst, int unitType)
    {
        IsFirst = isFirst;
        UnitType = unitType;
    }
}
```

You would use this as follows:

```
public enum Test
{
    [Descriptor(isFirst: true, unitType: 2)]
    Element
}
```

you already have the code to read this attribute in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can create yet another extention method for this.

```
public static object Create(this MyEnum enum)
{
    switch (enum)
    {
         case MyEnum.First:
              return new { IsFirst = true, UnitType = 1}];
         case MyEnum.Second:
              return new ...
         default:
              ...
    }
}
```

then use it like so:

```
dynamic first = MyEnum.First.Create();
var isFirst = first.IsFirst;
```

**but** *you really should consider creating a factory to create your objects*.