# Shared Enumeration classes between aggregates - folder and file structure in project

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregates

In a project I am creating based on DDD rules and patterns, I am currently designing my Aggregates in my Domain layer. What I would like to know, is **where to put the files that contain the definition of Enumeration classes (or other entities) that are shared between multiple differenet Aggregates.**

I will provide an example to make my question clearer:

Let's say I have two Aggregates, the ClubAggregate and the MatchAggregate, where the aggregate roots for these are `Club` and `Match` respectively. Now, both Club and Match should "have" a `League`. I have modeled League to be an Enumeration class because the only reason it exists is for categorization, it doesn't contain any business logic and could have been replaced by a simple enum, but I modeled it this way to take full advantage of the capabilities of OOP.

The folder structure in my project for these aggregates is **Domain/AggregatesModel/{aggregate_name}**, so for example the "Club.cs" file that contains the `Club` entity definition is located in Domain/AggregatesModel/ClubAggregate/Club.cs.

What is the best location to place the "League.cs" file that will contain the `League` Enumeration class defintion?

1. Create two different "League.cs" files with the same content and place each one in every Aggregate folder? (this doesn't feel right to me).
2. Place the "League.cs" file only in one of the Aggregates folder, and use the namespace to reference it in the other Aggregates?
3. Create a new folder called "SharedEntities" under Domain/AggregatesModel and place every file that contains a shared entity, enumeration class, etc. in there?

Please elaborate me on what would be the best approach to follow for files organization in my Domain layer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it seems to me that your `League` is more a value object than an entity.  
Are two leagues equals because of their value or because of their identity?

Comment: @rascio League enumeration classes have just two fields, Id and Name. Both Id and Name fields differentiates them from one another. Also, their values are pre-defined and they are never mutated during their lifetime. Their values are seeded at the DB only once at the startup of the application.

Comment: Yep, so they seems to be value objects to me not real entities if your application doesn't need to create new of them. You could also think to use a different approach for them, and do something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45093394/is-it-possible-to-add-custom-properties-to-c-sharp-enum-object without having to have them in the db at all (I don't know c# too much, but seems it seems to be the counterpart of an approach I used in java, in this way the enum entry would be the id and the name is just something associated with it)

Comment: To respond to your question, you are struggling with this because you see them as an entity, but they are not. If they would have been an entity you should have created a package for it. Value Objects instead are not owned by an entity, like having a VO `Meter` in one of your entity it doesn't mean that it owns the definition of what a meter is, VO can be shared by their nature.

Comment: By the way, to respond to your question, it should stay in its own package, I would avoid a `SharedEntities` as it doesn't make sense, all entities are "shared" in a certain sense, because each entity can have a relation to another one using its own id. So or you do your `LeagueAggregate` to make it explicit that is an independent aggregate, or you do a `ValueObjects` namespace/package that is shared with all the entities, but you should avoid option 1 and 2, as it is the same concept, and no other aggregate owns it.

Answer (score 1):

DDD does not teally have anything to say about folder structures.

But, don't create two versions of the same Enum class.in different namespaces unless you are expecting divergence of the League.cs for Club vs League.

I'd go for the shared folder.

Comment: Thanks for your response. You 're right, I won't create two different League classes in separate namespaces as League "means" the same thing in both Aggreagtes. I will go with the SharedEntities folder solution.